# Can't add command to Cog in discord,py

Tags: python, discord.py

I was trying to make a simple bot in python using cogs. But whenever I run my code it says command not found when command is there clearly. I have tried each and every thing but couldn't find any solution. Any help is much appreciated

So I have 2 files. One contains the cog and setup function and other one contains bot and other stuff. I tried putting print statement in the each function and i realized that program never calls the constructor of Test class in test_cog.py file.

--main_cog.py--

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents
import os

intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} is running..')
    bot.load_extension('./cogs/test_cog.py')
    print("file loaded")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

--test_cog.py--

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        print("Test cog loaded")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        print("inside ping command")
        await ctx.send("Pong from Cogs file!")

def setup(bot):
    print("inside setup function")
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

I tried each and every thing available on internet but nothing helped me. I was expecting bot to run without errors and give accurate response to my commands.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.0.0 `add_cog` and `load_extension` are asynchronous. That means you have to `await` them.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} is running..')
    await bot.load_extension('./cogs/test_cog.py')
    print("file loaded")
```

```py
async def setup(bot):
    print("inside setup function")
    await bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```